# Send email on buttonclick event in asp.net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I'm developing a web application where after filling in a registration form, I want a button click to send an email to the address which is specified in the textbox of that particular form.
Consider a registration form when filled by customer, is it possible to send a confirmation mail to the customer using the email ID which the customer inserted in the textbox of that form? 
I'm using asp.net 3.5 and MS sql 2005

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void SendMail()
    {
        // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
        var fromAddress = "Gmail@gmail.com";
        // any address where the email will be sending
        var toAddress = YourEmail.Text.ToString(); 
        //Password of your gmail address
        const string fromPassword = "Password";
         // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
        string subject = YourSubject.Text.ToString();
        string body = "From: " + YourName.Text + "\n";
        body += "Email: " + YourEmail.Text + "\n";
        body += "Subject: " + YourSubject.Text + "\n";
        body += "Question: \n" + Comments.Text + "\n";
        // smtp settings
        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        {
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        }
        // Passing values to smtp object
        smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
    }


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //here on button click what will done 
            SendMail();
            DisplayMessage.Text = "Your Comments after sending the mail";
            DisplayMessage.Visible = true;
            YourSubject.Text = "";
            YourEmail.Text = "";
            YourName.Text = "";
            Comments.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

Comment: hai thanks for ur advice.. i just wana knw is there ny other way where we can implement this email sending concept without inserting the password concept.... plzz sugest in this regard.. thanks in advnce..